# New Page for Drop down Box

Tags: javascript

This code works. It shows a image when a drop down box is selected and it also create a link for that image that can be clicked on.  I need it to open in a new page instead of the existing page.

I tried window.open  but that didnt work. I also tried href="_blank" but that just open a blank page.

```
    <script language="javascript">
    <!--

    function linkrotate(which){
    var mylinks=new Array()

    mylinks[0]=""
    mylinks[1]=""
    mylinks[2]=""
    mylinks[3]=""
    mylinks[4]=""
    mylinks[5]=""
    mylinks[6]=""

    window.location=mylinks[which]
    }


    function showimage()
    {
    if (!document.images)
    return
    document.images.pictures.src=
document.mygallery.picture.options[document.mygallery.picture.selectedIndex].value
    }
   //-->
   </script>
    <table style="width: 1016px; height: 230px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
      <div style="text-align: center;"> </div>
      <form name="mygallery">
        <div style="text-align: center;"> </div>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <select name="picture" size="1" onchange="showimage()">
        <option selected="selected" value="me.gif">PPT Slide</option>
        <option value="mon.gif">Monday</option>
        <option value="montier.gif">Monday Tier 3</option>
        <option value="tues.gif">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="tuestier">Tuesday Tier 3</option>
        <option value="wed.gif">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="wedtier.gif">Wednesday Tier 3</option>
        <option value="thurs.gif">Thursday</option>
        <option value="thurstier.gif">Thursday Tier 3</option>
        <option value="friday.gif">Friday</option>
        <option value="fridaytier.gif">Friday Tier 3</option>
        </select>
        </p>
      </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
      <p align="center"><a href="javascript:linkrotate(document.mygallery.picture.selectedIndex)" onmouseover="window.status='';return true"><img src="me.gif" name="pictures" border="0" height="400" width="600">
```

Comment: use `window.open(mylinks[which], '_blank');` instead of `window.location=mylinks[which]`

Comment: sidenote, dont use tables for page structure, use divs, and css..

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping your code simple, in your JavaScript you are calling the same DOM element more than you should when you could just set the attribute `onchange` of your select element like this:

```
<select name="picture" size="1" onchange="showimage(this)">
```

And reference it on your code like this:

```
function showimage(e){
    return document.images.pictures.src = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
}
```

---

Also, you can just define the array elements in the same variable definition, so you don't have to call the same variable twice:

```
var mylinks = [
    "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
    "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
    "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
    "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
    "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
    "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
    "http://www.placehold.it/200x200"
];
```

---

Then, just to open it on a new window you can use:

```
function linkrotate(which) {
    var mylinks = [
        "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
        "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
        "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
        "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
        "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
        "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
        "http://www.placehold.it/200x200"
    ];
    window.open(mylinks[which], '_blank');
}
```

***Note:*** First make sure you have the same amount of options than array elements, otherwise if you select the index 9 in your options but index 9 is not defined in your `myLinks` array, it will show up an empty window.

---

A solution for this would be to generate the options in your select element with JavaScript.

Based on your `mylinks` array:

```
function generateOptions() {
    let select = document.querySelector("#imageselect");
    mylinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = link;
        option.innerText = `Element ${index}`;
        select.appendChild(option);
    });
}
```

And your HTML of your select element would be:

```
<select id="imageselect" name="picture" size="1" onchange="showimage(this)"></select>
```

### Check it out:

**With options directly in HTML:**

```js
function linkrotate(which){
    var mylinks=[
     "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
      "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
      "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
      "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
      "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
      "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
      "http://www.placehold.it/200x200"
    ];
  console.log(which);
    window.open(mylinks[which], '_blank');
    }


function showimage(e){
    return document.images.pictures.src = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
}
```

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
      <div style="text-align: center;"> </div>
      <form name="mygallery">
        <div style="text-align: center;"> </div>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <select name="picture" size="1" onchange="showimage(this)">
        <option selected="selected" value="me.gif">PPT Slide</option>
        <option value="mon.gif">Monday</option>
        <option value="montier.gif">Monday Tier 3</option>
        <option value="tues.gif">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="tuestier.gif">Tuesday Tier 3</option>
        <option value="wed.gif">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="wedtier.gif">Wednesday Tier 3</option>
        <option value="thurs.gif">Thursday</option>
        <option value="thurstier.gif">Thursday Tier 3</option>
        <option value="friday.gif">Friday</option>
        <option value="fridaytier.gif">Friday Tier 3</option>
        </select>
        </p>
      </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
      <p align="center"><a href="javascript:linkrotate(document.mygallery.picture.selectedIndex)" onmouseover="window.status='';return true"><img src="me.gif" name="pictures" border="0" height="400" width="600">
```

**With options generated with JavaScript:**

```js
var mylinks=[
  "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
  "http://www.placehold.it/100x200",
  "http://www.placehold.it/230x260",
  "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
  "http://www.placehold.it/200x200",
  "http://www.placehold.it/200x200"
];

function linkrotate(which){
  console.log(which);
    window.open(mylinks[which], '_blank');
    }


function showimage(e){
    return document.images.pictures.src = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
}



function generateOptions(){
 let select = document.querySelector("#imageselect");
  mylinks.forEach((link,index)=>{
   let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = link;
    option.innerText = `Element ${index}`;
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
}

generateOptions();
```

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
      <div style="text-align: center;"> </div>
      <form name="mygallery">
        <div style="text-align: center;"> </div>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <select id="imageselect" name="picture" size="1" onchange="showimage(this)">
          
        </select>
        </p>
      </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
      <p align="center"><a href="javascript:linkrotate(document.mygallery.picture.selectedIndex)" onmouseover="window.status='';return true"><img src="me.gif" name="pictures" border="0" height="400" width="600">
```